# How to find a best match among combinations in C#

Tags: c#, collections, combinations, ienumerable, iequalitycomparer

Say I have a collection which has 5 properties.

[image]

My Input:
A=1;B=2;c=3;d=4;

Using this input i have to get the Property E ( which is exactly close to my input or nearly close to my input)

In this case my expected result is
[image]

Result A and Result C.

So should check the below combinations in code

```
if(A and B and C and D) all matches collection 
    take that;
    break;
else if(A and B and C) matches the collection
    take that;
    break;
else if (A and B and D) matches the collection 
    take that;
    break;
else if (A and B and D) matches the collection 
    take that;
else if (A and B) matches the collection 
    take that;
    break;
else if(A and C) matches the collection
    take that;
    break;
else if(A and D) matches the collection
    take that;
    break;
else if A matches the collection
    takethat;
    break;
else if B matches the collection
    take that;
    break;
else if c matches the collection
    take that;
    break;
else if D matches the collection
    take that;
    break;
else
    "No Match Found"
```

So when the number of properties to check is more , the more combinations we need to build . So i need to create a utility which build the combinations dynamically and check the comparison of objects. I can pass the properties as string array and can make the required combinations, but i have no clue how to access the object properties.
How to handle this situation ?

Comment: this giant wall of text is hard to read - could you format it a bit better?

Comment: copy and pasted from school work ? - are you just looking for an answer when you have the sudo code written in your 1st wall? do you want us to tell you that you probably want to make an object to store the results that your checking against then you could say object.A object.B etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom function in your class like:

```
public class CustomObject
{
    public CustomObject(string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4)
        : this(p1,p2,p3,p4,null)
    {
    }

    public CustomObject(string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4, string p5)
    {
        Prop1 = p1;
        Prop2 = p2;
        Prop3 = p3;
        Prop4 = p4;
        Prop5 = p5;
    }

    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
    public string Prop2 {get;set;}
    public string Prop3 {get;set;}
    public string Prop4 {get;set;}
    public string Prop5 {get;set;}

    public int NumberOfSameProps(CustomObject other)
    {
        return (Prop1 == other.Prop1 ? 1 : 0) +
               (Prop2 == other.Prop2 ? 1 : 0) +
               (Prop3 == other.Prop3 ? 1 : 0) +
               (Prop4 == other.Prop4 ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

And then all you have to do is get the items where the comparison returns the maximum value.

Usage:

```
CustomObject obj1 = new CustomObject("1","2","3",null,"Result A");
CustomObject comp = new CustomObject("1","2","3","4");
int nb = obj1.NumberOfSameProps(comp); // returns 3
```